# Vue 3: Each button click, generate new component and append as child in the target element

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have been searching for a simple solution to generate components in a Vue 3 app programmatically. So far, I've used `defineComponent` to extend the div component and attach it to the main component via `createApp` and `mount`:

**Main Component**

```
<template>
 <button type="button" v-on:click="addDiv"></button>
 <div id="app-main">
 </div>
</template>

<script>
 import {defineComponent, createApp} from 'vue'
 import Div from './components/Div.vue'

 export default{
  name: 'App',
  methods: {
   addDiv: () => {
    let newDiv = defineComponent({extends: Div});
    createApp(newDiv).mount("#app-main");
   }
  }
 }
</script>
```

**Div Component:**

```
<template>
 <div>This is a div</div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
  name: 'Div'
 }
</script>
```

My issue with this is that `mount` replaces everything in the target element. If you click the button 3 times, only 1 div appears instead of 3. I need a method where the code appends the component as a child in the target element allowing me to create as many div components as I want. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no such method What you're trying to do is not conventional. If you want to extend a template, you could modify element objects in render function. Otherwise you'll have to manipulate DOM manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `mount` as that is designed to mount a new Vue instance. What you want to use is the `<component :is="component_name">` feature and possibly have an array or other data structure containing the list of components you wish to have rendered.

For instance, consider the following simple example:

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
    // component config goes here, omitting for simplicity.
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        elements: []
    },
    methods: {
        addNewDiv() {
            this.elements.push({type: 'my-component'});
        }
    }
});
```

```
<div id="app">
    <component v-for="element in elements" :is="element.type"></component>
</div>
```

This will iterate over the `elements` array dynamically and will replace each instance of the `<component>` tag with whatever is defined by the array element.

Comment: This doesn't preserve the original template of Div. The problem is likely it wasn't designed to be extended in the first place

Comment: @EstusFlask I have a hard time understanding what you mean by preserving the original template. This would simply insert a custom `Div` component, or other custom component, by its component name programmatically. It would, by its very nature, use the child component's own template for rendering.